# Codeigniter SQL query no records in other table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I would like to join 2 tables but there is no record in the other table.

For example 
Table name: shop_items

- shop_item_id
- shop_item_sk
- shop_item_name

Table name: item_reviews

- item_review_id
- item_review_sk
- item_review_desc
- item_review_rate
- shop_item_sk
- item_review_by

The problem is that it the item details doesn't appear when it don't have any record in the item_reviews table

this is my SQL statement

```
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('shop_items')
    ->join('item_reviews', 'shop_items.shop_item_sk=item_reviews.shop_item_sk','inner')
    ->where('shop_items.shop_item_sk',$id)
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
    return $query->result();
```

I researched about UNION but I don't know how to use it in Codeigniter.
Advance thank you for those who can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use left outer join. Here shop_items table is the left table join item_reviews with it.

Comment: what if i need the AVG(item_review_rate) and count(item_review_id) where do i put it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with a left join ?

```
 $query = $this->db->select('*')
->from('shop_items')
->join('item_reviews', 'shop_items.shop_item_sk=item_reviews.shop_item_sk','left')
->where('shop_items.shop_item_sk',$id)
->limit(1)
->get();
return $query->result();
```